# Getting a value of 0 when dividing 2 longs in c#

Tags: c#, casting, int, long-integer

I am trying to divide the values of DriveInfo.AvailableFreeSpace & DriveInfo.TotalSize to try and get a percentage of it to use in a progress bar.

I need the end value to be an int as progressbar.value requires an int and the above methods return a long.

I have this as the values:

164660715520---AvailableFreeSpace

256058060800---TotalSize

When I try and set the progressbar.value using this method I also get an error:

progressBar1.Value=(int)(dInfo.AvailableFreeSpace/dInfo.TotalSize)*100;

When I use this code to try and get a value it just returns a 0.

```
label10.Text =  (((int)dInfo.AvailableFreeSpace/dInfo.TotalSize)*100).ToString();
```

I've even tried this and it doesn't work:

```
label10.Text = ((dInfo.AvailableFreeSpace/dInfo.TotalSize)*100).ToString();
```

I know I still have to do some formatting to get it to look good but whenever I run the code it just returns a 0.

Could it have something to do with the conversion from long to int?

Comment: The value of 164660715520/256058060800 is 0.64. That's why you're getting 0 I would imagine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Integer division returns only the integer part. So 3/5 will be 0. You'll need to treat at least one of the factors as a floating point number. Try this:

```
label10.Text =  (((int)((double)dInfo.AvailableFreeSpace/dInfo.TotalSize)*100)).ToString();
```

Comment: Now would I be able to just cast that into an int to get a whole number?

Comment: @Sempus if you only want the integer part, you can `*100` first.

Comment: In some cases, double is not big enough to cover long

Comment: decimal type is larger than than long which use 128 bit, double just use 64 bit, same with long

Comment: @Sempus: Ahh I get what you mean. Sure you can, just cast the final result to `int`.

Comment: @Cuong Le: I agree, but I doubt the amount of free space will exceed the max value of double.

Comment: Yea, I really only care about the whole number part(int) so the decimal part I really don't care about. Just getting percentages.

Answer (score 16):

The first way with casting `dInfo.AvailableFreeSpace` to `int` right away is not going to work, because the number `164660715520` that you are trying to cast does not fit in 32 bits. You need to stay in 64 bits as long as you can.

**The trick to avoiding floating-point arithmetics is to multiply by `100` first, and then do the division.**

As long as the number times `100` is within the allowed size (and in your case, it is) the result has a good precision:

```
label10.Text = ((100*dInfo.AvailableFreeSpace/dInfo.TotalSize)).ToString();
```

[Demo on ideone (prints 64).](http://ideone.com/r2tE6)

```
long total = 256058060800L;
long avail = 164660715520L;
var pct = (100*avail/total).ToString();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", pct); // 64
```

Answer (score 4):

The value is rounding down to 0, as `long` types cannot have decimal places, only whole integers.

Cast as a `decimal` type before multiplying by 100

For Example (In my case where I am calculating progress percentage for ProgressBar):

double someVariable = (double)longVariable1 / (double)longVariable2;

Code is given below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
    {
         web.ProgressChanged += new WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler(web_ProgressChanged);
    }

private void web_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        <strong>double t = (100 * (double)e.CurrentProgress / (double)e.MaximumProgress);</strong>
        if (t < 0)
            return;
        int c = (int)t;
        progressBar.Value = c;

        if (c == 100)
        {
            label1.Text = "Done";                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make your dInfo.AvailableFreeSpace and dInfo.TotalSize decimal or double type to avoid casts
Or

use`label10.Text =  (((double)dInfo.AvailableFreeSpace/dInfo.TotalSize)*100).ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late but I had this issue when trying to compare timespan's. Eventually I cast each timepsan to a string and manually computed the ratio

```
    private static double Improvement(string efficientTime, string inefficientTime)
    {
        var magnitude = Math.Pow(10, (inefficientTime.Length - efficientTime.Length));
        var time2 = (double) Convert.ToInt32(efficientTime.Substring(0, 5));
        var time1 = (double) Convert.ToInt32(inefficientTime.Substring(0, 5));
        var sigRatio = (time2 / time1);

        var sigPercent = sigRatio * magnitude;

        var improvement = sigPercent;
        return improvement;
    }
```